# Autofill method of Range class failed: VBA

Tags: excel, autofill, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm having trouble understanding where my code is falling down. I receive the message "Autofill method of Range class failed" after trying to implement an If statement.

My code is:

```
 Columns("H:H").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(C[-6] = ""Commodities Ags/Softs"", (IF(RC[-3]=R1C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R2C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R3C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R4C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R5C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R6C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R7C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R8C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R9C24,""Y"",""N"")))))))))))))))))),"""")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Columns("H:H"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

It fails at the last line, the If statement is fine, any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: Why not simply `Columns("H:H").FormulaR1C1 = ...`?

Comment: That works in theory but it freezes the excel sheet. I suppose I badly specified it, or not at all even, but I need a way to identify the last populated row and fill as far down as there

Comment: There are literally a thousand questions (already answered) about finding the last row. .. did you even google or search here on SO?

Comment: Siddharth answered it for me. You have to understand I have a remedial level of VBA, I didn't know the best way to go about what I was trying to do. And I am Googling but find it hard at times to apply what I find, apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Not an inconvenience, I'm just trying to teach you how to fish. You already recognized that you didn't really specify what you need -- and in response to that I said "You should google it!". If you had put those two pieces together, you would end up with @Sid's answer on your own :)

Comment: Haha touche. Cheers anyway, I feel like I've made serious strides since this morning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Col H
        lRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Enter the formula in one go
        .Range("H1:H" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(C[-6] = ""Commodities Ags/Softs"", " & _
                                            "(IF(RC[-3]=R1C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R2C24,""Y""," & _
                                            "(IF(RC[-3]=R3C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R4C24,""Y""," & _
                                            "(IF(RC[-3]=R5C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R6C24,""Y""," & _
                                            "(IF(RC[-3]=R7C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R8C24,""Y""," & _
                                            "(IF(RC[-3]=R9C24,""Y"",""N"")))))))))))))))))),"""")"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ya that's what I want to happen. Basically, I'm tring to say wherever column C = "Commodities Ags/Softs", then populate column H with the If statement, and if possible just paste the values i.e. Y or N.

Answer (score 0):

`Autofill` works like this:

```
SingleCell.AutoFill MoreCells
```

and you have

```
ColumnH.AutoFill ColumnH
```

If you want to use Autofill, it might looks like this

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("H1")
    .FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(C[-6] = ""Commodities Ags/Softs"", (IF(RC[-3]=R1C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R2C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R3C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R4C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R5C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R6C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R7C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R8C24,""Y"",(IF(RC[-3]=R9C24,""Y"",""N"")))))))))))))))))),"""")"
    .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(100, 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

I didn't autofill the whole column b/c that's a million rows and I don't have that kind of time.

Siddharth's R1C1 answer is the way to go, I just wanted to give you the heads up on Autofill.

Comment: Cheers for the heads up, I'm very unfamiliar with the syntax!